# How to expand RSS feed links on click

Tags: java, android, listview, rss, feed

I am designing a code in which I will post RSS feeds of posts on internet (Like news.) I am able to get the list of news from reuters RSS feed but the problem is I want the user to get full news when he clicks the news. But that is not happening. What do I need to enter in listview's on click listener for the news to expand.?

I have taken reference of [this project](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/News_Reader/Download_Free_code_SatuBH.htm) to bring the items in list view. Since its non clickable right now, I want to know how to make it click-able so that the user gets to read full post when he clicks any listview item.

I am confused since it will be automatically updating, how to keep the listview items opening the proper news when clicked.?

[image: This need to be expandable on click. But its not.]

In this image, I want Bawa kes ke SPRM to expand when the user clicks on it..

Comment: Implement onClick Listener to get the news in a web view

Comment: But how to give the link as it will be updated every now and then and hence i will not know the links for all of them..

Comment: Do you want to register listener which take updated url when item clicked?

Comment: yes.. I want to knkw how to get the updated URL everytime..